# Блокировка SELECT'ов к таблице во время индексации Sphinx

Tags: mysql, sphinx

Совсем недавно заметил, что при индексации таблицы Sphinx'ом, таблицу которую он индексирует заблокирована не только для записи, а и для чтения. Приходится ждать загрузку страницы до 10-ти секунд пока не завершится индексация. Таблица не маленькая(~150к записей) и редко обновляется поэтому стоит MyISAM. На сколько мне известно SELECT не создает блокировку на уровне таблиц в MyISAM, а только INSERT, UPDATE это делают.

Я провел тест. Тот же запрос из переменной sql_query с помощью которого обращается Sphinx, я выполнил в MySql с выключенным кэшем (SQL_NO_CACHE) дабы получить реальные цифры. Повторил я его несколько раз, время выполнения ~0.0020 сек, что я бы сказал очень быстро при выборке всех ~150к записей. Индексирование происходит по крону каждые 10 минут. И каждые 10 минут нельзя получить ничего из таблицы пока Sphinx не завершит. Страницы в которых нет SELECT'ов к этой таблице загружаются без каких-либо проблем во время индексации.

В чем же проблема? Вот мой конфиг, обыкновенный ничем не отличающийся от других.

```
source table
{

type = mysql
sql_host = localhost
sql_user = 
sql_pass = 
sql_db = table
sql_port = 3306


sql_query_pre = SET NAMES utf8
sql_query_pre = SET CHARACTER SET utf8


sql_query = SELECT id, cast, director FROM table ORDER BY id DESC

sql_field_string = cast

sql_field_string = director

sql_ranged_throttle = 0
}

index table
{
source = table

path = /home/sphinx/data/table

docinfo = extern

morphology = stem_enru

min_word_len = 1

charset_table = 0..9, A..Z->a..z, _, a..z, U+410..U+42F->U+430..U+44F, U+430..U+44F, U+401->U+0435, U+451->U+0435

min_infix_len = 2

index_exact_words = 1
}

indexer
{
mem_limit = 256M
}

searchd
{
listen = 3312

log = /home/sphinx/log/searchd.log

read_timeout = 5

max_children = 30

pid_file = /home/sphinx/log/searchd.pid
}
```

Comment: SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST сделайте во время индексации и посмотрите какие запросы выполняются и как они влияют на другие.

Comment: @Firepro выполняется запрос из переменной sql_query который в sphinx.conf. Его статус `Sending data`. Все запросы, что ниже имеют статус `Waiting for table level lock`. Через несколько секунд запрос от sphinx получает статус `Writing to net`. Нижние запросы все также заблокированы со статусом `Waiting for table level lock`. Есть идеи как лечить?

Answer (score 2):

Ответ [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2018903/1920758) и хорошее объяснение ситуации [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2018935/is-it-possible-to-issue-a-select-query-in-mysql-without-taking-any-read-locks).

Вы моежете установить `low-priority-updates = 1` в секии `[mysqld]` конфига MySQL `my.cnf`, чтобы повысить приоритет апддейтов.

Еще вариант - использовать RT индекс.

Еще вариант - используйте InnoDB.